Can we create a meeting with automated recording set to true in multi tenant azure app. It should be recorded even if the organizer in not present
I have created a multi-tenant application in Azure App Registration. In the backend application , we create online meeting through the refresh token a user (say manager) in the primary tenant using Microsoft Graph API. The 'recordAutomatically' property of the meeting is set to true. I add users (say 'mentors') from some other organization as an attendees to the meeting.
The meeting is shown in the calendar inside teams app of the mentor.
When the mentor joins the meeting, the recording starts, but when the meeting ends, the recording fails to upload. When I join the primary user (manager), the meeting uploads successfully.
I want the meeting to be recorded even if the primary user (manager) do no join the meeting.
Any related help would be appreciated. Been stuck with it for a long time.

Set "recordAutomatically": true

Did that. The meeting recording starts and ends, but it fails to upload if there in no one from the primary tenant.

AFAIK it is by design and the user of primary tenant must be present

Ok. Lets suppose I create meeting using the tokens of mentors. Fetching meetings recording requires OnlineMeetingRecording,Read.All permission. This permission requires a consent by the admin. If the learner is from some other tenant how will the permission be granted? For the same tenant leraner, admin can grant the permission from app registrations.

The permission can be granted using the global admin creds of learner tenant. Can I post an answer with details how to grant consent?

Sure. That would be very helpful. Please share the link here as well and try to be as detailed as you can as I am new to this. Thanks for your time.

Sure will post in sometime:)

Also @Rukmini , is it possible to add a co-organizer from another tenant? Would it work then, I mean would the recording be uploaded when the co-organizer is present event if it is in a different tenant ?

Yes you can try that

Yes you can try that as organizers and co organizer can record the meet

Let us continue this discussion in chat.


Note that: To automatically record a meeting organizer/co-organizer must be present in the meeting.


The home tenant user must be present in the meeting as guests cannot record a meeting.

In TenantA, I created a Multi-tenant Microsoft Entra ID application:

To grant this permission in TenantB for this application, use the below endpoint:
Make sure to login or ask the TenantB Global admin to login and Accept
https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/adminconsent?client_id=ClientIDOfTenantA
And the TenantB Global Admin user must login and Accept:

In TenantB, go to the Enterprise application blade and search the application:
And the permission will be granted, and you can check in the permissions blade

